# List containing 3 Spinner and 2 edit text in one row

Tags: android

I have list with 3 spinners and 2 edit texts in each row.Is it possible to handle it with listview?
I tried but due to get view method it is giving problem on onItemClick listeners of spinner or on text changed event of edit text..
Can anybody suggest me best approach for it?

Comment: Post your code please .

Comment: I can't share ma code..but can u suggest ki is it possible with list view?

Comment: of course it's possible. why don't you build a small generic test case first, then if you have problems, share that code.

Comment: `I have list with 3 spinners and 2 edit texts in each row.`. Please show how you put that in a list.

Comment: I dnt have problem while creating a lost but it's holder.edit text.ontextchanged event gets called every time whenever get view method gets called..nd thus changes done at one location gets reflected to other location too.

Comment: @greenapps can u share ur code please..

Comment: You should of course post your code and ask us to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a custom adapter it should be possible. If you have problems with your clicks it might help to disable some view from being clickable.

```
          android:clickable="false"
```

You can find a lot of tutorials on custom adapters for ListViews. Here is something for EditText inside a ListView:

http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/

Comment: Have you ever made a ListView where the items contained EditTexts? And could you edit?

Comment: I have done it before, but I don't have the code at hand. There are also tutorials on that: http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/